# Shortcut to auto generate interface methods in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I am coding in Typescript using Visual Studio Code. Is there a way to auto generate methods stubs which gets inherited in a class through an interface ?

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, can you please mark my answer?

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36110718/533837

Answer (score 10):

UPDATE: VS Code now supports this functionality out of the box. Just add the interface, the compiler will highlight the controller with red, right click on the light bulb on the left and click implement interface. Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: doesn't seem to be working for me. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44819656/vs-code-typescript-auto-implement-interface

Comment: @Ahmed-Anas
Is the file in which you write with the .ts extenstion? Because I have the lightbulb with version of VsCode

Comment: @knaos I don't see it either, using the ".ts" extension, with VSCode 1.13.1 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to auto generate methods stubs which gets inherited in a class through an interface

Not out of the box. And plugin API interface is not public yet.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Is there any other workaround ? or simply writing it manually is the way to go currently ?

Comment: Plug : You might want to work on a quickfix in atom-typescript : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#quickfix