# VSCode Implement Method Shortcut

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode, Exist, a way to implement the methods that are within an interface in typescript using some shortcut keys or set for it.

I searched on the website of Microsoft, and the web, but I have not found anything.

Comment: Can you please reconsider marking the correct answer?

Comment: Could you make @knaos 's answer the one marked as answered? Mine no longer is true.

Comment: Last seen back in '17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't such a shortcut by default.

You can search for an extension on the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/VSCode). I didn't find any.

Comment: can you mark @knoas 's answer as the correct one? Mine is no longer valid.

Comment: on Mac just press cmd and . together.

Answer (score 50):

UPDATE: VS Code now supports this functionality out of the box. Just add the interface, the compiler will highlight the controller with red, right click on the light bulb on the left and click implement interface.
Enjoy!

[image: Interface implementing]

Comment: Is there a shortcut for that?

Comment: @sowdri There is a shortcut for it, when your cursor is on the red underlined work press `ctrl+.`

Comment: It's worth noting that the code action won't appear if the interface you want to implement has only nullable/non-required members. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49430045/4028303

Comment: @JimShowalter It still works for me in the latest VSCode version.

Comment: My VSCode is only implementing properties from interfaces all of a sudden, and not methods...

Comment: I just tried it with 1.31.1 on win10 x64 and it works like a charm. THANKS! saves so much trouble. TS is really starting to feel like java 5 years ago (in a good way)

Comment: `cmd+.` on macos

Comment: Just tried it with VS Code 1.41 using 'implements OnChanges'.  The import statement is correctly and automatically updated (+1).  However, it does not add the OnChange method.  My class is underlined and when I click quick fix I get the option to add the method.  It jams it onto the first line causing other errors and adds a second import statement inside of with double quotes even though I have the preferences set to single (-2).

Answer (score 12):

Update: The shortcut in VsCode for accessing this quick action is the usual one: Ctrl + . (period).

The built-in functionality of VsCode implementing an interface was first resolved for me by upgrading and using the Visual Studio Code -Insiders version instead.

See: [VsCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) for downloading this edition of VsCode.

Note that using the insiders editions might impact other aspects of your apps, as the versions are more beta than the public VsCode editions.

[image: Implement Typescript interface built-in option in VsCode]

Comment: Although your post is very clear and well made, it is not an answer to this question... The question was about what the shortcut for that action is

Comment: @UTF_or_Death I updated my answer regarding the shortcut for triggering the quick action in VsCode.

Answer (score 9):

It will be "`ctrl+.`" for visual studio code linux version or click on the `light bulb icon`([image]).

Comment: So useful, literally spent 20mins researching, getting frustrated, nearly closed my project to use it visual studio. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

If you are using mac, the shortcut is CMD + .