# How to auto fill object properties respective to its type inference?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Take for example the simplest interfaces and types in TS:

```
// simple interface
interface Simple {
  a: string,
  b: number
}
```

Now lets create an object infer to this interface:

```
// simple object
const simple: Simple = {
  a: 'hello world',
  b: 10
}
```

As you can see, I need to fill `a` and `b` properties "manually". I actually need to guess or click on the type to get to probably another page and get dig in and in. This demo is simple, but sometimes there very complex structures and interfaces. As you can see, `a` and `b` are required so I anyway HAVE to provide them.

I have looked for but couldn't find: is there any solution so TS, or the code editor (VS Code for example), will just fill right in all the required properties and I will just fill them from the "template"? Instead of actually go and look for them and extract from the actually interface.

So I get something like that immediately after adding the `:Simple`:

```
// simple object
const simple: Simple = {
  a: string,
  b: number
}
```

Comment: Note that you're doing is *not* inferring the type; you've specified it explicitly, `const simple: Simple = ...`. TS isn't going to generate code in your editor for you, it's for transpiling the code you wrote, but your IDE may have features to help you (e.g. JetBrains IDEs would offer to "implement all members" when you write `const simple: Simple = {}`, expanding it to `const simple: Simple = {a: '', b: 0}`.

Comment: Yes that is what I want. Does someone know a plugin for VS Code doing the same?

Comment: I don't, and requests for off-site resources like VS Code plugins are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ya.. that has been already asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110718/vscode-implement-method-shortcut/56828490

Comment: Those things only apply to classes implementing interfaces, I don't see any useful suggestions in VS Code if I write `const simple: Simple = {}`.

Comment: This question is essentially a software recommendation. As such, it might fit better on [softwarerecs.se].