# VS Code typescript: auto-implement interface

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have an interface in typescript and want to autoimplement it.

I've been looking around and according to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110718/vscode-implement-method-shortcut) and [github issue,](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7073) this feature should already be there but it's not working for me. No lightbulb appears.

[image: Implement Interface Autocomplete]

Comment: Is the file in which you write with the .ts extenstion? Because I have the lightbulb with version of VsCode 1.13.1

Answer (score 1):

If the interface has no required members, then the code action/quick fix will not appear on the class definition.

```
interface IFoo {
    x?: number
    y?: number
}

class Foo implements IFoo {
    // no code action shown
}
```

But if the interface has at least one required member, then the code action will appear, and when clicked, will implement *all* the members, including the nullable ones.

```
interface IFoo {
    x: number
    y?: number
}

class Foo implements IFoo {
    // code action will appear.
    // will implement both x and y? when clicked
}
```

This behavior is due to TypeScript's compiler, not VS Code. You can track this issue as it related to VS Code [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46286), and the TypeScript functionality [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22770).